color glitches when rendering in cycles
I'm new to blender and had an issue following a tutorial on youtube making a pan and when i come to render it i have like a glitchy color on the handle but it dont happen on evee only on cycles any help?
EVEE

Cycles


Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

IT  dont want to upload my file but the handle texture is just a normal color ntg else

Then, could you provide screen captures of your interface ? Showing modifiers, textures, shaders, render engines setup, normals, ... ?
